# Column with Null values from a query

Tags: sql, oracle, informix

I'm trying to translate a query from Informix to Oracle.
In Informix this query

```
SELECT  a.base_imp,
        b.num_exp,
        c.tip_canon_unit,
        b.cod_tip_ben,
        b.dat_cr_ini,
        b.dat_cr_fi,
        b.cod_emb,
        b.nif_Abo_liq,
        0 as usuari,
        '' as nom_usu,
        '' as acotacio 
FROM  OUTER dpt_mant_can_reg_3 a,
      dpt_mant_canreg_2 b,
      OUTER dpt_mant_can_reg_1 c
WHERE a.cod_emb=b.cod_emb and b.cod_emb=c.cod_embassament and 
      a.cod_tip_ben = b.cod_tip_ben 
      and b.cod_tip_ben = c.cod_tip_ben and a.nif_abo_liq=b.nif_abo_liq 
      and b.nif_abo_liq = '39203275M' and b.cod_emb = 1
and (
     (b.dat_cr_ini >= date('01/01/2018') and b.dat_cr_ini <= 
     date('31/12/2018')) 
     or (b.dat_cr_fi >= date('01/01/2018') and b.dat_cr_fi <= 
     date('31/12/2018') 
     or (b.dat_cr_ini <= date('01/01/2018') and b.dat_cr_fi >= 
     date('31/12/2018')) 
     and a.dat_cr_ini = date('01/01/2018') and c.dat_cr_ini = 
     date('01/01/2018')));
```

Gives as a result 19 rows, with all data in the first column (a.base_imp field) with a NULL value.
It happens because there is no coincidences at WHERE clause (a.dat_cr_ini = date('01/01/2018'))  but Informix allows to give results, putting NULLS in the field columns from tables with no coincidences.

If I try to do the same with Oracle

```
SELECT a.base_imp,
   b.num_exp,
   c.tip_canon_unit,
   b.cod_tip_ben,
   b.dat_cr_ini,
   b.dat_cr_fi,
   b.cod_emb,
   b.nif_Abo_liq,
   0 as usuari,
   '' as nom_usu,
   '' as acotacio 
FROM  dpt_mant_can_reg_3 a LEFT OUTER JOIN dpt_mant_canreg_2 b ON 
   (a.cod_emb=b.cod_emb and a.cod_tip_ben = b.cod_tip_ben and 
    a.nif_abo_liq=b.nif_abo_liq)
   LEFT OUTER JOIN dpt_mant_can_reg_1 c ON 
   (b.cod_emb=c.cod_embassament and b.cod_tip_ben = c.cod_tip_ben ) 
WHERE 1=1 and b.nif_abo_liq = '39203275M' and b.cod_emb = 1 
   AND   ((b.dat_cr_ini >= to_date('01/01/2018','DD/MM/YYYY') and 
   b.dat_cr_ini <= to_date('31/12/2018','DD/MM/YYYY')) or 
   (b.dat_cr_fi >= to_date('01/01/2018','DD/MM/YYYY') and 
   b.dat_cr_fi <= to_date('31/12/2018','DD/MM/YYYY') or 
   (b.dat_cr_ini <= to_date('01/01/2018','DD/MM/YYYY') and 
   b.dat_cr_fi >= to_date('31/12/2018','DD/MM/YYYY')) 
   and a.dat_cr_ini = to_date('01/01/2018','DD/MM/YYYY') and 
   c.dat_cr_ini = to_date('01/01/2018','DD/MM/YYYY')))
```

There is no results(0 rows) Oracle doesn't allow to retrieve data from this query if there are not coincidences. How I can modify the query to retrieve rows in the same way that Informix does?

Comment: The Oracle equivalent of `date('01/01/2018')` is `date '2018-01-01'`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the date conditions to the `on` clause.  You should also learn about the `date` keyword.

Your `where` conditions transform the outer joins into inner joins.  Usually the correct solution is to move the conditions to the `on` clause.  It looks something like this:

```
FROM dpt_mant_can_reg_3 a LEFT OUTER JOIN
     dpt_mant_canreg_2 b
     ON a.cod_emb = b.cod_emb and
        a.cod_tip_ben = b.cod_tip_ben and 
        a.nif_abo_liq = b.nif_abo_liq and
        b.nif_abo_liq = '39203275M' and
        b.cod_emb = 1 and
        ( (b.dat_cr_ini >= date '2018-01-01' and
           b.dat_cr_ini <= date '2018-12-31'
          ) or
          (b.dat_cr_fi >= date '2018-01-01' and
           b.dat_cr_fi <= date '2018-12-31'
          )
        )
        . . . LEFT OUTER JOIN
     dpt_mant_can_reg_1 c
     ON b.cod_emb  = c.cod_embassament and
        b.cod_tip_ben = c.cod_tip_ben and
        c.dat_cr_ini = date '2018-01-01'
 WHERE a.dat_cr_ini = date '2018-01-01'
```

I would also advise you to change the table aliases.  `a`, `b`, and `c` are meaningless.  Use abbreviations for the table names, such as `cr3`, `cr2`, and `cr1`.

Answer (score 0):

The Informix-style OUTER join is an interesting construct, not quite like anything in the standard or any other DBMS.

Your original query has the FROM clause and main joining conditions like:

```
FROM  OUTER dpt_mant_can_reg_3 a,
      dpt_mant_canreg_2 b,
      OUTER dpt_mant_can_reg_1 c
WHERE a.cod_emb = b.cod_emb AND b.cod_emb = c.cod_embassament AND 
      a.cod_tip_ben = b.cod_tip_ben 
      AND b.cod_tip_ben = c.cod_tip_ben AND a.nif_abo_liq = b.nif_abo_liq
```

The 'dominant' table has the alias `b` and the other two are outer-joined to it.  In your proposed translation, you have:

```
FROM dpt_mant_can_reg_3 a
LEFT OUTER JOIN dpt_mant_canreg_2 b ON 
     (a.cod_emb = b.cod_emb and a.cod_tip_ben = b.cod_tip_ben and 
      a.nif_abo_liq = b.nif_abo_liq)
LEFT OUTER JOIN dpt_mant_can_reg_1 c ON 
     (b.cod_emb = c.cod_embassament and b.cod_tip_ben = c.cod_tip_ben)
```

This has the wrong table as the 'dominant' table — consequently, you ***will*** get different results; you're writing a different query.

At minimum, you need the FROM clause to look more like:

```
 FROM dpt_mant_canreg_2 b
 LEFT OUTER JOIN dpt_mant_can_reg_3 a
      ON  a.cod_emb = b.cod_emb
      AND a.cod_tip_ben = b.cod_tip_ben
      AND a.nif_abo_liq = b.nif_abo_liq
 LEFT OUTER JOIN dpt_mant_can_reg_1 c
      ON  b.cod_emb = c.cod_embassament
      AND b.cod_tip_ben = c.cod_tip_ben
```

This has the correct join structure (the equivalent join structure to the Informix-style OUTER join notation) and that is a pre-requisite to getting the rest to work.

The remainder of the WHERE clause is filter conditions, and they're complicated to understand.  You have:

```
      and b.nif_abo_liq = '39203275M' and b.cod_emb = 1
and (
     (b.dat_cr_ini >= date('01/01/2018') and b.dat_cr_ini <= 
     date('31/12/2018')) 
     or (b.dat_cr_fi >= date('01/01/2018') and b.dat_cr_fi <= 
     date('31/12/2018') 
     or (b.dat_cr_ini <= date('01/01/2018') and b.dat_cr_fi >= 
     date('31/12/2018')) 
     and a.dat_cr_ini = date('01/01/2018') and c.dat_cr_ini = 
     date('01/01/2018')))
```

The format does not make the structure clear.  However, we can reformat it so it looks like:

```
   AND b.nif_abo_liq = '39203275M'
   AND b.cod_emb = 1
   AND (
        (b.dat_cr_ini >= DATE('01/01/2018') AND b.dat_cr_ini <= DATE('31/12/2018')) 
        OR
        (b.dat_cr_fi >= DATE('01/01/2018') AND b.dat_cr_fi <= DATE('31/12/2018') 
         OR (b.dat_cr_ini <= DATE('01/01/2018') AND b.dat_cr_fi >= DATE('31/12/2018')) 
             AND a.dat_cr_ini = DATE('01/01/2018')
             AND c.dat_cr_ini = DATE('01/01/2018')
        )
       )
```

That's still fairly complex, not least because it doesn't use BETWEEN/AND where it could.  This is, I think, equivalent to the above:

```
   AND b.nif_abo_liq = '39203275M'
   AND b.cod_emb = 1
   AND (
         b.dat_cr_ini BETWEEN DATE('01/01/2018') AND DATE('31/12/2018')
         OR
         b.dat_cr_fi  BETWEEN DATE('01/01/2018') AND DATE('31/12/2018') 
         OR
         ( b.dat_cr_ini <= DATE('01/01/2018') AND
           b.dat_cr_fi  >= DATE('31/12/2018') AND
           a.dat_cr_ini  = DATE('01/01/2018') AND
           c.dat_cr_ini  = DATE('01/01/2018')
         )
       )
```

The third term in the OR is the one that runs the risk of producing different results between standard SQL outer joins and Informix-style outer joins because it filters on the three tables (the other two filter only on the dominant table).  Specifically, with Informix-style joins, if there are rows in the table aliassed as `a` that satisfy the 'start on or before 2018-01-01 and finish on or after 2018-12-31' condition, those rows will be selected regardless of whether there are rows in the tables aliassed `b` and `c` with the specified date equality conditions. If there isn't a row in `b` that matches, then nulls will be supplied; similarly for `c`.

By contrast, the standard SQL outer join will apply the filter to the result of the outer join, and rows where the contribution from `b` or `c` is null will be eliminated.

There's at least a moderate chance that the standard SQL filtering is what you want; it is what you'd get in Informix if you used the standard SQL outer join notation.

The conditions shown above still use the Informix-style DATE function.  A date such as `DATE('31/12/2018')` (which assumes a US-style date convention) can be converted to standard SQL DATE notation DATE '2018-12-31' (which is locale-independent).

Quietly ignoring that horribly subtle point about how the filtering differs, the query could be assembled to read:

```
SELECT a.base_imp,
       b.num_exp,
       c.tip_canon_unit,
       b.cod_tip_ben,
       b.dat_cr_ini,
       b.dat_cr_fi,
       b.cod_emb,
       b.nif_abo_liq,
       0 as usuari,
       '' as nom_usu,
       '' as acotacio
  FROM dpt_mant_canreg_2 b
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dpt_mant_can_reg_3 a
       ON  a.cod_emb = b.cod_emb
       AND a.cod_tip_ben = b.cod_tip_ben
       AND a.nif_abo_liq = b.nif_abo_liq
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dpt_mant_can_reg_1 c
       ON  b.cod_emb = c.cod_embassament
       AND b.cod_tip_ben = c.cod_tip_ben
 WHERE b.nif_abo_liq = '39203275M'
   AND b.cod_emb = 1
   AND (
         b.dat_cr_ini BETWEEN DATE '2018-01-01' AND DATE '2018-12-31'
         OR
         b.dat_cr_fi  BETWEEN DATE '2018-01-01' AND DATE '2018-12-31' 
         OR
         ( b.dat_cr_ini <= DATE '2018-01-01' AND
           b.dat_cr_fi  >= DATE '2018-12-31' AND
           a.dat_cr_ini  = DATE '2018-01-01' AND
           c.dat_cr_ini  = DATE '2018-01-01'
         )
       )
```

I'd like to check this against the test database schema and test data given in the question so that the desired and actual results could be compared.  Sadly, I can't — there was no test schema nor any test data given in the question, and no sample expected results.  It would be nice to be able to test the refactored version of the WHERE clause using the Informix-style OUTER notation to check whether that is clean.

Comment: @Arseni: If you add a minimal schema and carefully selected sample data to the question, along with the desired results (or actual results from that sample data with the original query), add a comment here with `@Jonathan` to let me know I should look again.  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  An MCVE query would probably not include the three constant columns — `usuari`, `nom_usu`, `acotacio`.